# Gundam-style anime where the main character spends an entire episode chased by girls

Tags: story-identification, anime

This anime was set in a kind of medieval/modern setting. The main character who is a guy spent an entire episode toward the end of the anime running away from all the girls in an academy because, I assume, they wanted to tie him to a bed and use him as a device for their sexual pleasure(!)

I also remember a battle where this mecha-train was firing upon, I think, a ship. I know there was a siege wall with cannons on it firing on an advancing army, kind of like the walls with cannons from Attack on Titan.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=19rBhQbyqug

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here ; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)  and here [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question).

Comment: That sounds similiar to what happned in chapters 3 and 5 from "Isekai no Seikishi Monogatari".